# Power BI - count closed rolling items

Tags: powerbi

I could not find similar topic or an answer.

I have the following data **in excel**

```
ID  CLOSE DATE  Status      DAY   Total Closed per day  Closed rolling  Open
1               Open        DAY 1 8     0               0               8
2               Open        DAY 1 8     0               0               8
3   11/10/2019  Closed      DAY 1 8     1               1               7
4   12/10/2019  Closed      DAY 2 8     2               3               6
5   12/10/2019  Closed      DAY 2 8     2               3               5
6   13/10/2019  Closed      DAY 3 8     1               4               4
7   14/10/2019  Closed      DAY 4 8     1               5               3
8   15/10/2019  Closed      DAY 5 8     1               6               2
```

Where

```
DAY  = 
  VAR _days = DATEDIFF(Sheet1[START_DATE_PACK],Sheet1[CLOSE DATE], DAY)
RETURN "DAY " & _days
```

The rest from excel.

The graph I need in **Power BI** is this one as taken from ***excel***

[image]

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What is wrong with the graph you have already produced? What needs fixing and what have you already tried that didn't work?

Comment: I need it in Power BI and not excel.

Comment: What is preventing you from building the same chart in Power BI?

Comment: I do not know how to code Closed rolling column.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a rolling total column but this would be less flexible, it's probably better to handle as a measure.

Below is the standard pattern for a rolling total measure adapted to your column names:

```
Closed Rolling :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( MyTable[Closed Per Day] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( MyTable[Close Date] ),
        MyTable[Close Date] <= MAX ( MyTable[Close Date] )
    )
)
```